# I can not get my Microsoft SQL Server trigger to run properly

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am trying to have this trigger run each time information is inserted into a single table then run the information along with Visual Studio which it will send the information as a text file into my folder where I can use the information at a later time to log transactions.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE VDtoText
(
    AccountNumber INT NOT NULL,
    GarmentNumber INT NOT NULL,
    TicketNumber INT NOT NULL,
    SlotNum INT NULL,
    DateTimeAdded DateTime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
)
```

Here is the trigger:

```
/* first run these both separately after creating table */ 
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO 

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO
RECONFIGURE;  
GO

CREATE TRIGGER UpdateInsertPlz
ON VDtoText  
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)

    SELECT @sql = 'bcp SUVOAS.dbo.VDtoText out "C:\Users\benso\OneDrive\Desktop\Test\Final2\WC\WCtoPOS.txt" -c -t"," -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME
    PRINT @sql

    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql
END;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @sql = 'bcp SUVOAS.dbo.VDtoText out "C:\Users\benso\OneDrive\Desktop\Test\Final2\WC\WCtoPOS.txt" -c -t"," -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME

PRINT @sql

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

This code by itself will properly send the information how I would like, but while it is in a trigger it just continues to attempt to execute and I just see a wheel spin the whole time on Microsoft SQL and Visual Studio continuously returns:

> The thread 0x2a34 has exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread 0x3d38 has exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread 0x562c has exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread 0x5e14 has exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread 0x31fc has exited with code 0 (0x0).

and sends no information of the inserted data to the table.

Please Help :)

Comment: Even if you get this to work: you should **NOT** do any heavy-lifting and compute-intensive work in a trigger! The trigger executes in the context of the SQL statement that caused it to be fired - and that transaction is delayed until the trigger either completes, or rolls back. So make your triggers very **small, nimble, and fast** - and calling an external utility like `bcp` most certainly violates those principles! You need to rethink your strategy here....

Comment: @marc_s is there a better way you might suggest?

Comment: Yes, definitely: in your trigger, you should *only* make an insert into a "command" table (or whatever you want to call it) - nothing more. A separate process (e.g. a SQL Server Agent job, or a scheduled command line utility) should then read that "command" table on a regular basis, and if there's anything to be done, that separate process should then do the time-consuming and/or compute-intensive job - separate from your trigger and your transaction.